# Disabling Google Cast discovery without WiFi

Tags: google-cast

My app is integrated with the Google Cast SDK to cast videos to a Chromecast.

Since the device needs to be connected to a WiFi network to be able to connect and cast, I thought that maybe I could disable device discovery if the device is not connected to a WiFi network, so I don't waste battery and CPU cycles with useless tasks.

Then I wondered: do I really need to do this manually or is the SDK smart enough to make this decision?

I didn't find any information about it in the documentation, and I have no idea where else to look for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should leave device discovery to the Cast SDK which has been optimized for various networking conditions.

Comment: I'd think so, but do you have any sources that support this claim?
Edit: just saw you're a developer at Google, which makes it more reliable, but it would be really nice to have it written in the docs.